# How to use prefetch_related in many to many relation django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have some models (models.py):

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Permission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class User_Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class User_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Serializer
```

serializers.py

```
class User_Serializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['user_permissions', 'email']
```

I want to optimize api. How can I use prefetch_related there? I set related name to UserPermission model and User.objects.prefetch_related('related_name'). But queries are not optimized

Comment: Share your serializer.

Comment: But you here exclude the `user_permissions`, hence prefetching these makes no sense. Exactly *what* relations do you serialize?